# JavaScript: Should I use a method or function for events?

Tags: javascript, function, events, methods, mouse

I have a program I'm working on, rather starting, for a website that I have been making. The program is an HTML5 Canvas with JavaScript (and jQuery) game. To do this I have to be able to tell where in the canvas the user clicks. I could do it like this:

```
mouse = new Object();
mouse = {
   //Assign Temp Values 
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   click: function(event) {
       //Code to get location and assign to mouse.x and mouse.y then handle click
   }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#canvas').click(function(evt) {mouse.click(evt);}); 
});
```

Or I could do it like this:

```
mouse = new Object();
mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#canvas').click(function(evt) {
        //Code here to get location and assign to mouse.x and mouse.y and then handle click
    });
});
```

I know in this case that it is less code for the latter and I've seen questions like this for other languages but I was wondering if there are any advantages to using a method for event handling or a separate function in JavaScript. For example: one being good programming practice, or more efficient, or even easier to read. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're concerned with practice: 1. Use the `var` keyword. 2. `mouse= new Object(); mouse = {...}` is redundant, as the original object is lost immediately and you define an inline one.

Comment: Thanks, I normally remember `var`, I don't know what happened there. But thanks for clarifying on the `new Object()` declaration. Honestly I've always wondered on whether good practice dictated I do that because I have seen it a lot with something like a `new Array()` etc.

Comment: Hey no problem. With array it is important because an array is not just an object; it has it's own built-in prototype, with special methods like push, etc. But then you still wouldn't initialize it twice. An inline array could be expressed `var myarr = ['some', 'vals', 'here'];`

Answer (score 0):

The only significant thing that occurs to me is this: if you use a method, then `this` is set to the object the method was called on.  However, depending on browser, `this` may have a more useful value coming into the event handler, which would be good to preserve.  You could always pass it to the method, but if you use a function instead, the value of `this` is available unchanged inside the function body.

Comment: Thanks! Honestly the difference in effectiveness of `this` hadn't occurred to me being relatively new to the full extent of OOP in JS. Out of curiosity, what did you mean with depending on the browser? I guess I was just being optimistic but I thought `this` was _actually_ something that was common among browsers... Rather I hoped it was.

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise, the second method is slightly faster because you have one less method call, but there's no significant difference.

http://jsperf.com/method-vs-callback